# Sync a folder between macbook, pc and time capsule as backup

Tags: windows, mac, network-drive

I have a time capsule set up that has backups of the entire system of both my macbook and my pc.

Now I would like to add a folder on the time capsule drive, for instance 'Projects'. Which has a backup of all my projects and is automatically synced with a folder on both my macbook and my pc.
How can I do that?

-I don't want to work on the time capsule network drive, I just want it to have a backup.

-If I change something on my macbook, the file on pc should be changed. Vice versa as well.

-I would like it to update automatically and not manually have to update the folder on any of my machines

Comment: Have you considered using the same folder? I mean, for example, export the PC folder to your Mac using SMB, then set automatic backup to Time Capsule. You will then have 1 folder, the same one on both mac and pc. This will only work, of course, if both mac and pc are connected to the same network.

Comment: I would like to work on either my pc or macbook without having the other one powered on.

Example: I work abroad on a project on my macbook, when I'm home it automatically syncs to the time capsule. When I then turn on my pc, it automatically syncs with the time capsule so I have the update on there as well.
SVN software would work but I was wondering if there is something much simpler.

Comment: Well, yes. Just set up your Time Capsule to export the directory to the pc using SMB. Also the Time Capsule to mirror the mac's directory. When you change something on the mac, that chage will propagate to the TC and, since the pc is mounting the TC directory, any changes will also be available there. This should work as long as the only portable computer is the mac. That is, if the only changes you make, off network, will be done on the mac.